# Conversion of custom data to spacy ner format

Tags: spacy

I am using flair to train a custom NER model, but i want to also try out spacy, but my data is currently in this format

```
No O
1320160208478 B-NUM
P O
R O
Name O
Ryan B-PER
Dsouza B-PER
```

Any suggestions on how i could format this in the spacy NER format?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spacy has built-in converters for some common formats, but this isn't quite one of them. I think the easiest one to convert to would be the CoNLL 2003 NER format, which would need two additional space-separated columns with placeholder values in between the words and tags so that the IOB tags are in the 4th column:

```
No _ _ O
1320160208478 _ _ B-NUM
P _ _ O
R _ _ O
Name _ _ O
Ryan _ _ B-PER
Dsouza _ _ B-PER
```

Put blank lines between sentences and if you have multiple documents in one file you can add this between documents to separate them.

```
-DOCSTART- -X- O O
```

Then you can use a built-in converter:

```
python -m spacy convert -c ner input.txt output_dir
```

(Also, are you sure two `B-PER` tags in a row is correct for `Ryan Dsouza` in your data?)

Comment: okay ,let me check this out, Yes i have 2 b-per tags in a row

Comment: The question is whether `Ryan Dsouza` is one person or two. If it's one person it should probably be `B-PER I-PER`.

Comment: Hi @Ryan, have you find any workaround for this? I have data with exactly same format like yours. Thanks!